# How to link a FPGA design and a NIOSll processor as a sigle FPGA design in DE0 nano

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

Hi am trying to integrate a NIOSll processor in my already existing FPGA design so that finally i have a single FPGA solution. I have a signal monitoring unit designed in VHDL and i need to connect the created design to a NIOSll processor for my calculation and displaying the result. I have found ways to do things individually but i want both elements in single FPGA. 
Is is possible? 
If yes then please let me know how. I am using ALTERA DE0-Nano board. Please look into the image. 
Part inside red is what i want to implement. 
[image: FPGA design]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest interface to the Nios II processor are it's [PIO (Parallel I/O)](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii5v3.pdf) peripherals which you can read at any time from the program running on your Nios II.

Once you have configured your Nios II system in Qsys/SOPC Builder, make sure that *Create block symbol file* on the Generation tab is ticked (it already was with my setup) before you click the *Generate* button. Then, you will be able to do *Insert* -> *Symbol* on your schematic and choose the generated symbol file. Then, you can wire up that block with your other parts of the design.

It might be worthwhile considering to remove the two `para2ser_28bit` instances, depending on your application, as you can make a single PIO peripheral instance up to 32 bits wide. If you need more you can use more PIOs, although care must then be taken to ensure the data is always consistent.

Also, the [Nios Forum](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=37) is a good place to look for help if you have problems.

Comment: Thank u very much for your help. i will out n let u know if i face any problem. :)